# Chainlink callback protection

Tags: chainlink

How do i make sure the callback function of a call to a chainlink node isn't called by anyone else?

I understand I need to make it public so the node can call it back but I want to protect it from anyone else calling it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example where we limited access to the `_callback()`
Now it can only be called by the address specified in the variable **ChainlinkAddress**.

Hope it helps;

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.3;


contract SmartContract {

    // Chainlink node account/address 
    address ChainlinkAddress;

    modifier onlyChainlink() {
        require(msg.sender == ChainlinkAddress);
        _;
    }

    // It's advised to add onlyOwner modifeir to this function, so others can't modify the ChainlinkAddress;
    function setChainlinkAddress(address addr) external {
            ChainlinkAddress = addr;
    }


    function _callback() public view onlyChainlink returns(bool sucess) {
       //do something
        sucess = true;

    }
    
}
```

**NOTE**:To use only owner, I recommend `OpenZeppelin` `Ownable` library to implement such functionality.

Comment: But if I add onlyOwner then the chainlink node won't be able to call it back with the response from the get query I made

Comment: What is the address/account your chainlink node is using to call it?

Comment: Why does it matter? I'm using the chainlink testnet node for testing for now

Comment: It's possible to write a custom modified that will allow only that address (chainlink address) to call the function.  For example, onlyChainlink modified.

Comment: I think I understand. So I need to add a condition that only the chainlink oracle node that I am calling can call the callback function. Do you have an example of something like this? And thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: Yes, I will write code example first thing in the morning (Its now late in the evening where I live, so I feel tied). Bit I will have code sample for you tomorrow.